anchor-spl v0.30.1 solana-spl 1.18.17 error[E0308]: mismatched types
I'm building solana smart contract with anchor.
anchor version is 0.30.1
solana-cli version is 1.18.17
first time, I built and deploy smart contract without any issue.
But after I add this two lines, I get too long errors.
use anchor_spl::token::{self, Token, TokenAccount, Mint, Transfer};
use std::cmp::min;

I don't understand why this occurs error.
How can I solve this issue?
error[E0308]: mismatched types
   --> src/extension/confidential_transfer/instruction.rs:784:27
    |
784 |         instructions.push(verify_pubkey_validity(None, proof_data));
    |                      ---- ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected `Instruction`, found `solana_program::instruction::Instruction`
    |                      |
    |                      arguments to this method are incorrect
    |
    = note: `solana_program::instruction::Instruction` and `Instruction` have similar names, but are actually distinct types
note: `solana_program::instruction::Instruction` is defined in crate `solana_program`
   --> src/instruction.rs:332:1
note: `Instruction` is defined in crate `solana_program`
   --> src/instruction.rs:329:1
    = note: perhaps two different versions of crate `solana_program` are being used?
note: method defined here
   --> /home/runner/work/platform-tools/platform-tools/out/rust/library/alloc/src/vec/mod.rs:1880:12

error[E0308]: mismatched types
   --> src/extension/confidential_transfer/instruction.rs:887:27
    |
887 |         instructions.push(verify_zero_balance(None, proof_data));
    |                      ---- ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected `Instruction`, found `solana_program::instruction::Instruction`
    |                      |
    |                      arguments to this method are incorrect
    |
    = note: `solana_program::instruction::Instruction` and `Instruction` have similar names, but are actually distinct types
note: `solana_program::instruction::Instruction` is defined in crate `solana_program`
   --> src/instruction.rs:332:1
note: `Instruction` is defined in crate `solana_program`
   --> src/instruction.rs:329:1
    = note: perhaps two different versions of crate `solana_program` are being used?
note: method defined here
   --> /home/runner/work/platform-tools/platform-tools/out/rust/library/alloc/src/vec/mod.rs:1880:12

error[E0308]: mismatched types
    --> src/extension/confidential_transfer/instruction.rs:1018:27
     |
1018 |         instructions.push(verify_withdraw(None, proof_data));
     |                      ---- ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected `Instruction`, found `solana_program::instruction::Instruction`
     |                      |
     |                      arguments to this method are incorrect
     |
     = note: `solana_program::instruction::Instruction` and `Instruction` have similar names, but are actually distinct types
note: `solana_program::instruction::Instruction` is defined in crate `solana_program`
    --> src/instruction.rs:332:1
note: `Instruction` is defined in crate `solana_program`
    --> src/instruction.rs:329:1
     = note: perhaps two different versions of crate `solana_program` are being used?
note: method defined here
    --> /home/runner/work/platform-tools/platform-tools/out/rust/library/alloc/src/vec/mod.rs:1880:12

error[E0308]: mismatched types
    --> src/extension/confidential_transfer/instruction.rs:1111:27
     |
1111 |         instructions.push(verify_transfer(None, proof_data));
     |                      ---- ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected `Instruction`, found `solana_program::instruction::Instruction`
     |                      |
     |                      arguments to this method are incorrect
     |
     = note: `solana_program::instruction::Instruction` and `Instruction` have similar names, but are actually distinct types
note: `solana_program::instruction::Instruction` is defined in crate `solana_program`
    --> src/instruction.rs:332:1
note: `Instruction` is defined in crate `solana_program`
    --> src/instruction.rs:329:1
     = note: perhaps two different versions of crate `solana_program` are being used?
note: method defined here
    --> /home/runner/work/platform-tools/platform-tools/out/rust/library/alloc/src/vec/mod.rs:1880:12

error[E0308]: mismatched types
    --> src/extension/confidential_transfer/instruction.rs:1204:27
     |
1204 |         instructions.push(verify_transfer_with_fee(None, proof_data));
     |                      ---- ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected `Instruction`, found `solana_program::instruction::Instruction`
     |                      |
     |                      arguments to this method are incorrect
     |
     = note: `solana_program::instruction::Instruction` and `Instruction` have similar names, but are actually distinct types
note: `solana_program::instruction::Instruction` is defined in crate `solana_program`
    --> src/instruction.rs:332:1
note: `Instruction` is defined in crate `solana_program`
    --> src/instruction.rs:329:1
     = note: perhaps two different versions of crate `solana_program` are being used?
note: method defined here
    --> /home/runner/work/platform-tools/platform-tools/out/rust/library/alloc/src/vec/mod.rs:1880:12

error[E0308]: mismatched types
   --> src/extension/confidential_transfer/verify_proof.rs:197:48
    |
197 |                         context_state_account: equality_proof_context_state_account_info.key,
    |                                                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected `solana_program::pubkey::Pubkey`, found `Pubkey`
    |
    = note: `Pubkey` and `solana_program::pubkey::Pubkey` have similar names, but are actually distinct types
note: `Pubkey` is defined in crate `solana_program`
   --> src/pubkey.rs:88:1
note: `solana_program::pubkey::Pubkey` is defined in crate `solana_program`
   --> src/pubkey.rs:96:1
    = note: perhaps two different versions of crate `solana_program` are being used?

error[E0308]: mismatched types
   --> src/extension/confidential_transfer/verify_proof.rs:198:50
    |
198 |                         context_state_authority: context_state_account_authority_info.key,
    |                                                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected `solana_program::pubkey::Pubkey`, found `Pubkey`
    |
    = note: `Pubkey` and `solana_program::pubkey::Pubkey` have similar names, but are actually distinct types
note: `Pubkey` is defined in crate `solana_program`
   --> src/pubkey.rs:88:1
note: `solana_program::pubkey::Pubkey` is defined in crate `solana_program`
   --> src/pubkey.rs:96:1
    = note: perhaps two different versions of crate `solana_program` are being used?

error[E0308]: mismatched types
   --> src/extension/confidential_transfer/verify_proof.rs:200:21
    |
195 |                 &zk_token_proof_instruction::close_context_state(
    |                  ----------------------------------------------- arguments to this function are incorrect
...
200 |                     lamport_destination_account_info.key,
    |                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected `solana_program::pubkey::Pubkey`, found `Pubkey`
    |
    = note: `Pubkey` and `solana_program::pubkey::Pubkey` have similar names, but are actually distinct types
note: `Pubkey` is defined in crate `solana_program`
   --> src/pubkey.rs:88:1
note: `solana_program::pubkey::Pubkey` is defined in crate `solana_program`
   --> src/pubkey.rs:96:1
    = note: perhaps two different versions of crate `solana_program` are being used?
note: function defined here
   --> src/zk_token_proof_instruction.rs:364:8

error[E0308]: mismatched types
   --> src/extension/confidential_transfer/verify_proof.rs:195:17
    |
194 |               invoke(
    |               ------ arguments to this function are incorrect
195 | /                 &zk_token_proof_instruction::close_context_state(
196 | |                     ContextStateInfo {
197 | |                         context_state_account: equality_proof_context_state_account_info.key,
198 | |                         context_state_authority: context_state_account_authority_info.key,
199 | |                     },
200 | |                     lamport_destination_account_info.key,
201 | |                 ),
    | |_________________^ expected `Instruction`, found `solana_program::instruction::Instruction`
    |
    = note: `solana_program::instruction::Instruction` and `Instruction` have similar names, but are actually distinct types
note: `solana_program::instruction::Instruction` is defined in crate `solana_program`
   --> src/instruction.rs:332:1
note: `Instruction` is defined in crate `solana_program`
   --> src/instruction.rs:329:1
    = note: perhaps two different versions of crate `solana_program` are being used?
note: function defined here
   --> src/program.rs:132:8

error[E0308]: mismatched types
   --> src/extension/confidential_transfer/verify_proof.rs:213:48
    |
213 |                           context_state_account: ciphertext_validity_proof_context_state_account_info
    |  ________________________________________________^
214 | |                             .key,
    | |________________________________^ expected `solana_program::pubkey::Pubkey`, found `Pubkey`
    |
    = note: `Pubkey` and `solana_program::pubkey::Pubkey` have similar names, but are actually distinct types
note: `Pubkey` is defined in crate `solana_program`
   --> src/pubkey.rs:88:1
note: `solana_program::pubkey::Pubkey` is defined in crate `solana_program`
   --> src/pubkey.rs:96:1
    = note: perhaps two different versions of crate `solana_program` are being used?

error[E0308]: mismatched types
   --> src/extension/confidential_transfer/verify_proof.rs:215:50
    |
215 |                         context_state_authority: context_state_account_authority_info.key,
    |                                                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected `solana_program::pubkey::Pubkey`, found `Pubkey`
    |
    = note: `Pubkey` and `solana_program::pubkey::Pubkey` have similar names, but are actually distinct types
note: `Pubkey` is defined in crate `solana_program`
   --> src/pubkey.rs:88:1
note: `solana_program::pubkey::Pubkey` is defined in crate `solana_program`
   --> src/pubkey.rs:96:1
    = note: perhaps two different versions of crate `solana_program` are being used?

error[E0308]: mismatched types
   --> src/extension/confidential_transfer/verify_proof.rs:217:21
    |
211 |                 &zk_token_proof_instruction::close_context_state(
    |                  ----------------------------------------------- arguments to this function are incorrect
...
217 |                     lamport_destination_account_info.key,
    |                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected `solana_program::pubkey::Pubkey`, found `Pubkey`
    |
    = note: `Pubkey` and `solana_program::pubkey::Pubkey` have similar names, but are actually distinct types
note: `Pubkey` is defined in crate `solana_program`
   --> src/pubkey.rs:88:1
note: `solana_program::pubkey::Pubkey` is defined in crate `solana_program`
   --> src/pubkey.rs:96:1
    = note: perhaps two different versions of crate `solana_program` are being used?
note: function defined here
   --> src/zk_token_proof_instruction.rs:364:8

error[E0308]: mismatched types
   --> src/extension/confidential_transfer/verify_proof.rs:211:17
    |
210 |               invoke(
    |               ------ arguments to this function are incorrect
211 | /                 &zk_token_proof_instruction::close_context_state(
212 | |                     ContextStateInfo {
213 | |                         context_state_account: ciphertext_validity_proof_context_state_account_info
214 | |                             .key,
...   |
217 | |                     lamport_destination_account_info.key,
218 | |                 ),
    | |_________________^ expected `Instruction`, found `solana_program::instruction::Instruction`
    |
    = note: `solana_program::instruction::Instruction` and `Instruction` have similar names, but are actually distinct types
note: `solana_program::instruction::Instruction` is defined in crate `solana_program`
   --> src/instruction.rs:332:1
note: `Instruction` is defined in crate `solana_program`
   --> src/instruction.rs:329:1
    = note: perhaps two different versions of crate `solana_program` are being used?
note: function defined here
   --> src/program.rs:132:8

error[E0308]: mismatched types
   --> src/extension/confidential_transfer/verify_proof.rs:230:48
    |
230 |                         context_state_account: range_proof_context_state_account_info.key,
    |                                                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected `solana_program::pubkey::Pubkey`, found `Pubkey`
    |
    = note: `Pubkey` and `solana_program::pubkey::Pubkey` have similar names, but are actually distinct types
note: `Pubkey` is defined in crate `solana_program`
   --> src/pubkey.rs:88:1
note: `solana_program::pubkey::Pubkey` is defined in crate `solana_program`
   --> src/pubkey.rs:96:1
    = note: perhaps two different versions of crate `solana_program` are being used?

error[E0308]: mismatched types
   --> src/extension/confidential_transfer/verify_proof.rs:231:50
    |
231 |                         context_state_authority: context_state_account_authority_info.key,
    |                                                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected `solana_program::pubkey::Pubkey`, found `Pubkey`
    |
    = note: `Pubkey` and `solana_program::pubkey::Pubkey` have similar names, but are actually distinct types
note: `Pubkey` is defined in crate `solana_program`
   --> src/pubkey.rs:88:1
note: `solana_program::pubkey::Pubkey` is defined in crate `solana_program`
   --> src/pubkey.rs:96:1
    = note: perhaps two different versions of crate `solana_program` are being used?

error[E0308]: mismatched types
   --> src/extension/confidential_transfer/verify_proof.rs:233:21
    |
228 |                 &zk_token_proof_instruction::close_context_state(
    |                  ----------------------------------------------- arguments to this function are incorrect
...
233 |                     lamport_destination_account_info.key,
    |                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected `solana_program::pubkey::Pubkey`, found `Pubkey`
    |
    = note: `Pubkey` and `solana_program::pubkey::Pubkey` have similar names, but are actually distinct types
note: `Pubkey` is defined in crate `solana_program`
   --> src/pubkey.rs:88:1
note: `solana_program::pubkey::Pubkey` is defined in crate `solana_program`
   --> src/pubkey.rs:96:1
    = note: perhaps two different versions of crate `solana_program` are being used?
note: function defined here
   --> src/zk_token_proof_instruction.rs:364:8

error[E0308]: mismatched types
   --> src/extension/confidential_transfer/verify_proof.rs:228:17
    |
227 |               invoke(
    |               ------ arguments to this function are incorrect
228 | /                 &zk_token_proof_instruction::close_context_state(
229 | |                     ContextStateInfo {
230 | |                         context_state_account: range_proof_context_state_account_info.key,
231 | |                         context_state_authority: context_state_account_authority_info.key,
232 | |                     },
233 | |                     lamport_destination_account_info.key,
234 | |                 ),
    | |_________________^ expected `Instruction`, found `solana_program::instruction::Instruction`
    |
    = note: `solana_program::instruction::Instruction` and `Instruction` have similar names, but are actually distinct types
note: `solana_program::instruction::Instruction` is defined in crate `solana_program`
   --> src/instruction.rs:332:1
note: `Instruction` is defined in crate `solana_program`
   --> src/instruction.rs:329:1
    = note: perhaps two different versions of crate `solana_program` are being used?
note: function defined here
   --> src/program.rs:132:8

error[E0308]: mismatched types
   --> src/extension/confidential_transfer/verify_proof.rs:373:48
    |
373 |                         context_state_account: equality_proof_context_state_account_info.key,
    |                                                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected `solana_program::pubkey::Pubkey`, found `Pubkey`
    |
    = note: `Pubkey` and `solana_program::pubkey::Pubkey` have similar names, but are actually distinct types
note: `Pubkey` is defined in crate `solana_program`
   --> src/pubkey.rs:88:1
note: `solana_program::pubkey::Pubkey` is defined in crate `solana_program`
   --> src/pubkey.rs:96:1
    = note: perhaps two different versions of crate `solana_program` are being used?

error[E0308]: mismatched types
   --> src/extension/confidential_transfer/verify_proof.rs:374:50
    |
374 |                         context_state_authority: context_state_account_authority_info.key,
    |                                                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected `solana_program::pubkey::Pubkey`, found `Pubkey`
    |
    = note: `Pubkey` and `solana_program::pubkey::Pubkey` have similar names, but are actually distinct types
note: `Pubkey` is defined in crate `solana_program`
   --> src/pubkey.rs:88:1
note: `solana_program::pubkey::Pubkey` is defined in crate `solana_program`
   --> src/pubkey.rs:96:1
    = note: perhaps two different versions of crate `solana_program` are being used?

error[E0308]: mismatched types
   --> src/extension/confidential_transfer/verify_proof.rs:376:21
    |
371 |                 &zk_token_proof_instruction::close_context_state(
    |                  ----------------------------------------------- arguments to this function are incorrect
...
376 |                     lamport_destination_account_info.key,
    |                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected `solana_program::pubkey::Pubkey`, found `Pubkey`
    |
    = note: `Pubkey` and `solana_program::pubkey::Pubkey` have similar names, but are actually distinct types
note: `Pubkey` is defined in crate `solana_program`
   --> src/pubkey.rs:88:1
note: `solana_program::pubkey::Pubkey` is defined in crate `solana_program`
   --> src/pubkey.rs:96:1
    = note: perhaps two different versions of crate `solana_program` are being used?
note: function defined here
   --> src/zk_token_proof_instruction.rs:364:8

error[E0308]: mismatched types
   --> src/extension/confidential_transfer/verify_proof.rs:371:17
    |
370 |               invoke(
    |               ------ arguments to this function are incorrect
371 | /                 &zk_token_proof_instruction::close_context_state(
372 | |                     ContextStateInfo {
373 | |                         context_state_account: equality_proof_context_state_account_info.key,
374 | |                         context_state_authority: context_state_account_authority_info.key,
375 | |                     },
376 | |                     lamport_destination_account_info.key,
377 | |                 ),
    | |_________________^ expected `Instruction`, found `solana_program::instruction::Instruction`
    |
    = note: `solana_program::instruction::Instruction` and `Instruction` have similar names, but are actually distinct types
note: `solana_program::instruction::Instruction` is defined in crate `solana_program`
   --> src/instruction.rs:332:1
note: `Instruction` is defined in crate `solana_program`
   --> src/instruction.rs:329:1
    = note: perhaps two different versions of crate `solana_program` are being used?
note: function defined here
   --> src/program.rs:132:8

error[E0308]: mismatched types
   --> src/extension/confidential_transfer/verify_proof.rs:390:29
    |
390 | ...                   transfer_amount_ciphertext_validity_proof_context_state_account_info.key,
    |                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected `solana_program::pubkey::Pubkey`, found `Pubkey`
    |
    = note: `Pubkey` and `solana_program::pubkey::Pubkey` have similar names, but are actually distinct types
note: `Pubkey` is defined in crate `solana_program`
   --> src/pubkey.rs:88:1
note: `solana_program::pubkey::Pubkey` is defined in crate `solana_program`
   --> src/pubkey.rs:96:1
    = note: perhaps two different versions of crate `solana_program` are being used?

error[E0308]: mismatched types
   --> src/extension/confidential_transfer/verify_proof.rs:391:50
    |
391 |                         context_state_authority: context_state_account_authority_info.key,
    |                                                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected `solana_program::pubkey::Pubkey`, found `Pubkey`
    |
    = note: `Pubkey` and `solana_program::pubkey::Pubkey` have similar names, but are actually distinct types
note: `Pubkey` is defined in crate `solana_program`
   --> src/pubkey.rs:88:1
note: `solana_program::pubkey::Pubkey` is defined in crate `solana_program`
   --> src/pubkey.rs:96:1
    = note: perhaps two different versions of crate `solana_program` are being used?

error[E0308]: mismatched types
   --> src/extension/confidential_transfer/verify_proof.rs:393:21
    |
387 |                 &zk_token_proof_instruction::close_context_state(
    |                  ----------------------------------------------- arguments to this function are incorrect
...
393 |                     lamport_destination_account_info.key,
    |                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected `solana_program::pubkey::Pubkey`, found `Pubkey`
    |
    = note: `Pubkey` and `solana_program::pubkey::Pubkey` have similar names, but are actually distinct types
note: `Pubkey` is defined in crate `solana_program`
   --> src/pubkey.rs:88:1
note: `solana_program::pubkey::Pubkey` is defined in crate `solana_program`
   --> src/pubkey.rs:96:1
    = note: perhaps two different versions of crate `solana_program` are being used?
note: function defined here
   --> src/zk_token_proof_instruction.rs:364:8

error[E0308]: mismatched types
   --> src/extension/confidential_transfer/verify_proof.rs:387:17
    |
386 |               invoke(
    |               ------ arguments to this function are incorrect
387 | /                 &zk_token_proof_instruction::close_context_state(
388 | |                     ContextStateInfo {
389 | |                         context_state_account:
390 | |                             transfer_amount_ciphertext_validity_proof_context_state_account_info.key,
...   |
393 | |                     lamport_destination_account_info.key,
394 | |                 ),
    | |_________________^ expected `Instruction`, found `solana_program::instruction::Instruction`
    |
    = note: `solana_program::instruction::Instruction` and `Instruction` have similar names, but are actually distinct types
note: `solana_program::instruction::Instruction` is defined in crate `solana_program`
   --> src/instruction.rs:332:1
note: `Instruction` is defined in crate `solana_program`
   --> src/instruction.rs:329:1
    = note: perhaps two different versions of crate `solana_program` are being used?
note: function defined here
   --> src/program.rs:132:8

error[E0308]: mismatched types
   --> src/extension/confidential_transfer/verify_proof.rs:406:48
    |
406 |                         context_state_account: fee_sigma_proof_context_state_account_info.key,
    |                                                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected `solana_program::pubkey::Pubkey`, found `Pubkey`
    |
    = note: `Pubkey` and `solana_program::pubkey::Pubkey` have similar names, but are actually distinct types
note: `Pubkey` is defined in crate `solana_program`
   --> src/pubkey.rs:88:1
note: `solana_program::pubkey::Pubkey` is defined in crate `solana_program`
   --> src/pubkey.rs:96:1
    = note: perhaps two different versions of crate `solana_program` are being used?

error[E0308]: mismatched types
   --> src/extension/confidential_transfer/verify_proof.rs:407:50
    |
407 |                         context_state_authority: context_state_account_authority_info.key,
    |                                                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected `solana_program::pubkey::Pubkey`, found `Pubkey`
    |
    = note: `Pubkey` and `solana_program::pubkey::Pubkey` have similar names, but are actually distinct types
note: `Pubkey` is defined in crate `solana_program`
   --> src/pubkey.rs:88:1
note: `solana_program::pubkey::Pubkey` is defined in crate `solana_program`
   --> src/pubkey.rs:96:1
    = note: perhaps two different versions of crate `solana_program` are being used?

error[E0308]: mismatched types
   --> src/extension/confidential_transfer/verify_proof.rs:409:21
    |
404 |                 &zk_token_proof_instruction::close_context_state(
    |                  ----------------------------------------------- arguments to this function are incorrect

...
I think this is because version matching issue.
Why I get this issue with anchor?

I started having the same issue yesterday...

To fix this problem, you can downgrade Solana v2 dependencies by manually editing your lock file or simply running:
cargo update -p solana-zk-token-sdk@2.0.1 --precise 1.18.17


You have a few options to fix the build:
Use a command line argument to specify a version of the build tools
As of cargo build-sbf that comes bundled with Solana v1.16, you can use the --tools-version argument to use a different version of the build tools. Version 1.39 of the build tools contains a Rust compiler at 1.72, so you can run:
cargo build-sbf --tools-version v1.39

Upgrade to Solana tools 1.18
Upgrade to the Solana 1.18 tools, which defaults to v1.39 of the build tools:
solana-install init 1.18.0

Note at the time of writing Anchor was not ready for 1.18.
Set your solana-program version
As a last ditch effort, you can set your build to use v1.17 of solana-program by specifying the version in your Cargo.toml:
cargo add solana-program@"=1.17"

This is recommended by Solana Rust getting started Guide.
If you intend to publish your program crate, it will be much harder for others to use, forcing them onto exactly one version of solana-program. If any other crate in the build does the same thing, then it will be impossible to build.
